# Does "Lithium" have any meaning in Christianity?

Tags: terminology, origin

I was surfing around and found the following from [this link](https://www.songfacts.com/facts/nirvana/lithium):

> Erin from Tulsa, Ok: It is said that Kurt got inspired to this song,
> during the time he lived at his friend Jesse Reed's family. Jesse's
> parents was born-again Christians, and apparently they are reflected
> in Lithium as the person who 'found God'.

My question is that Does the word "Lithium" mean something in Christianity?

I did a research and found out that the word "Lithium" is coming from the Greek word lithos meaning stone, but I can't find any connection between lithium and Christianity and "a person who found God".

Comment: If you Google 'Lithium song wiki' you will find a link to a song, produced in 1990 about someone who becomes religious. It is thought the 'lithium' reference is to medication provided for a certain disorder. There is no connection to the Christian religion.

Answer (score 1):

**Does “*Lithium*” have any meaning in Christianity?**

Lithium has no direct meaning in Christianity.

[Lithium](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/1_s-Block_Elements/Group__1%3A_The_Alkali_Metals/Z003_Chemistry_of_Lithium_(Z3)) is the lightest of all metals and is named from the Greek work for stone (*lithos*). It is the first member of the Alkali Metal family. It is less dense than water (with which it reacts) and forms a black oxide in contact with air.

The Greek [***Lithos***](https://www.biblestudytools.com/lexicons/greek/nas/lithos.html) is thus defined as a stone. It could metaphorically refer to Christ.

The Nirvana song **Lithium** is about a man who turns to religion amid thoughts of suicide. Nirvana first recorded "Lithium" in 1990 but then re-recorded the song the following year for Nevermind.

> [**"Lithium"**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_(Nirvana_song)) is a song by American rock band Nirvana. It appears as the fifth track and third single from their second album Nevermind (1991). Written by frontman Kurt Cobain, the song is about a man who turns to religion amid thoughts of suicide. Nirvana first recorded "Lithium" in 1990 but then re-recorded the song the following year for Nevermind.
>
> Released as the third single from Nevermind in July 1992, "Lithium" peaked at number 64 on the US Billboard Hot 100 and number 11 on the UK Singles Chart. It was also a number 1 hit in Finland and a top 5 hit in Ireland and Portugal. The accompanying music video, directed by Kevin Kerslake, is a montage of concert footage.

Interesting that [**Nirvana**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana) chose this name do a song. Nirvana is often associated with Buddhist spirituality and not Christianity. And lithium salts, are primarily used as a psychiatric medication, making as sort of interior nirvana so to speak.

> Lithium compounds, also known as lithium salts, are primarily used as a psychiatric medication. They are primarily used to treat bipolar disorder and treat major depressive disorder that does not improve following the use of antidepressants. In these disorders, it reduces the risk of suicide. Lithium is taken orally. - [Lithium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_(medication))

Comment: Indeed, the song represents religiosity as a sort of "spiritual lithium" and is, in this way, not very complementary.  Much like Karl Marx calling religion the "opiate of the masses".